# Facing issue while installing packages into library in shinyapp.io

Tags: shinyapps

After deployed the R application successfully, getting error message while displaying the dashboard in webpage(An error has occurred. The application failed to start.) by stating that

```
"Installing packages into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages(new.packages) :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : unable to install packages
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted"
```

So, Without removing all installing packages from the R code, Can you please suggest, is there any way to take support of necessary packages, in free version of shinyapps.io?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to have your app install packages in shinyapps.io? I'm pretty sure you can't do that. Any app deployed to shinyapps.io is dependent on making sure the packages required to run the app are available in shinyapps.io. That is part of what the rsconnect package does when you begin to deploy your app. If your app deploys successfully, then the package dependencies should be available in shinyapps.io.

Try removing any "install.packages" code and deploy again.